# Loading file into pandas DataFrame without column header not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file which I want to read with pandas. Later I want to save that text file in csv format and I also want to add column names while saving csv file.

When my file is saved in csv format, the first row is replaced by the column names. This is my code

```
df = pd.read_csv('files.txt', delim_whitespace= True, header=0) 

d = dict(zip(df.columns[::],
         ['Column{}'.format(x) for x in range(len(df.columns[::]))]))
```

Finally, I want to rename the column names and everything is work except my new column names replace the first rows

```
df = df.rename(columns = d)
df.to_csv('test.csv', index= 0)
```

I am not sure why my first row is replaced with my column names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`header=0` means "I want the header to be the taken from the 0<sup>th</sup> row of my file".

You instead want `header=None`, which means "my file does not have a header at all".

---

Note, you can shorten your renaming script to

```
df.columns = 'Column' + df.columns.astype(str)
```

Which modifies the column headers in-place.

Comment: Small point, I don't believe it's technically correct to say the column headers are modified "in-place". The right hand side of your equation consists of a new index object with different pointers to immutable objects. [Aside, most Pandas `inplace` methods aren't actually any more efficient.]

Comment: @jpp "In place" ... with respect to the original DataFrame as opposed to using a function which returns a copy with the modified headers.... some disambiguation required.

Comment: @coldspeed, Yeh I guess there are multiple interpretations, I'm taking the raw reading. It's not like NumPy "in-place" where it matters (memory allocation).

Answer (score 3):

You can using `add_prefix`

```
df.add_prefix('columns_')
```